# Oracle/SQL Find Date or Closest date to specified date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query within oracle which creates a value.
The underlying table does not always contain a match for a specific date. So i have to either find the record with the date specified or find the closest date below the specified date.

```
SUM(CASE 
            WHEN S.VAL_SECURITY NOT IN ('GBP')
                AND E.SECURITY_ID NOT IN ('GBP')
                THEN (
                        (((amount) * - 1) / nvl(s.minor_per_unit, 1)) * (
                            SELECT EXCHANGE_RATE
                            FROM ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES
                            WHERE ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES.SECURITY_ID = E.SECURITY_ID
                                AND VAL_DATE = TO_DATE('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                            )
                        ) * (
                        SELECT EXCHANGE_RATE
                        FROM ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES
                        WHERE SECURITY_ID = S.VAL_SECURITY
                            AND VAL_DATE = TO_DATE('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                        )
            WHEN S.VAL_SECURITY IN ('GBP')
                AND E.SECURITY_ID NOT IN ('GBP')
                THEN (
                        (((amount) * - 1) / nvl(s.minor_per_unit, 1)) * (
                            SELECT EXCHANGE_RATE
                            FROM ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES
                            WHERE ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES.SECURITY_ID = E.SECURITY_ID
                                AND VAL_DATE = TO_DATE('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                            )
                        )
            ELSE ((amount) * - 1) / nvl(s.minor_per_unit, 1)
END) GBP_VALUE
```

The code in question is

```
E.SECURITY_ID AND VAL_DATE = TO_DATE('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

So assuming it doesn't find a record for the specified date then it needs to find the max date record closest to but below the specified date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: I think you should use joins instead of using so many sub queries for EXCHANGE_RATE

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: You could do an `ORDER BY` in the query, and have it set to order descending with the query results, and just take the first row returned. (Assuming you know there aren't any dates beyond the one you're trying to compare it to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this? I haven't verified it.

```
    val_date =
(SELECT val_date
   FROM (SELECT MAX (b.val_date) val_date,
                MIN (TO_DATE ('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - b.val_date)
                   diff
           FROM PREVIOUS_PRICES b
          WHERE     SECURITY_ID = E.SECURITY_ID
                AND status_date <= TO_DATE ('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         UNION ALL
         SELECT MIN (val_date),
                MIN (b.val_date - TO_DATE ('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
           FROM PREVIOUS_PRICES b
          WHERE     SECURITY_ID = E.SECURITY_ID
                AND status_date > TO_DATE ('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         ORDER BY 2)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for top 1 in this select :

```
SELECT EXCHANGE_RATE 
FROM ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
AND ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES.SECURITY_ID=E.SECURITY_ID 
AND VAL_DATE <= TO_DATE('05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
ORDER BY VAL_DATE DESC
```

Try this edited , with ROWNUM = 1 in the where condition

Comment: Oracle doesn't support TOP keyword

Comment: Hello, please try with the edited select above, sorry about the MS SQL syntax i did earlier with top 1.

Comment: That won't work either; rownum is processed before order by. You probably want `fetch first 1 row only`

Comment: ROWNUM doesn't play nicely with ORDER BY: the ROWNUM is assigned **before** the result set is sorted. There are plenty of questions tagged  [`[oracle]+[top-n]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+top-n) to explain this. But as @kfinity says, `fetch first 1 row only` is the one to choose, providing you're on Oracle 12c or later.

Answer (score 0):

Use one more embedded SQL Level

```
SELECT EXCHANGE_RATE
  FROM ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES
 WHERE ISET.PREVIOUS_PRICES.SECURITY_ID = E.SECURITY_ID
       AND VAL_DATE = (
       SELECT MAX(val_date)
         FROM iset.previous_prices
        WHERE val_date <= TO_DATE ( '05/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) 
         and PREVIOUS_PRICES.SECURITY_ID = E.SECURITY_ID);
```